# Extracting tweets of a hashtag tweeted from a specific location using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

I tried to extract all the tweets of hash tag **tweeted from a specific location** like below

```
Query query = new Query("Obama");
GeoLocation gl = new GeoLocation(40.7127,74.0059); // geo location of Newyork
query.setCount(100);
query.setLocale("en");
query.setLang("en");
query.setGeoCode(gl, 50, "Query.MILES");
```

But, I got an **empty result**. I got all the tweets on **Obama** before using the **setGeoCode** method. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Call `query.setGeoCode` without quotes around `Query.MILES`:

```
query.setGeoCode(gl, 50, Query.MILES);
```